# Using PowerShell and the New-SPWeb command, how can I add a site to a site collection with the -UseParentTopNav argument?

Tags: powershell

Whats the correct format of the `New-SPWeb` command when using the `UseParentTopNav` argument?

I'm trying to add a new site, I've tried passing in the following

```
New-SPWeb -url "http://server" -Template "STS#0" -Name "test99" -Description "test99"  -UseParentTopNav 1
```

and

```
New-SPWeb -url "http://server" -Template "STS#0" -Name "test99" -Description "test99"  -UseParentTopNav true
```

they both give error message

```
New-SPWeb : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '1'.
At line:2 char:11
+  New-SPWeb <<<<  -url "http:/server" -Template "STS#0" -Name "test99" -Description "test99"  -UseParentTopNav 1
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-SPWeb], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewWeb
```

and

```
New-SPWeb : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'true'.
At line:3 char:11
+  New-SPWeb <<<<  -url "http://onlm45005wkhxn1:33333" -Template "STS#0" -Name "test99" -Description "test99"  -UseParentTopNav true
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-SPWeb], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewWeb
```

If I run the help command

> get-help New-SPWeb -full

it gives me this information.

> ```
> -UseParentTopNav <SwitchParameter>
>     Specifies that the same top-level navigation bar as the parent site is to be used for this site.
>     Required?                    false
>     Position?                    Named
>     Default value                
>     Accept pipeline input?       False
>     Accept wildcard characters?  false
> ```

What format should the `<SwitchParameter>` be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Switch parameters just need to be by themself, no argument is needed:

```
New-SPWeb -url "http://server" -Template "STS#0" -Name "test99" -Description "test99" -UseParentTopNav
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.switchparameter(v=vs.85).aspx

> A switch parameter is a parameter that
>   may, or may not, be specified when the
>   command is run. If the parameter is
>   specified, the Windows PowerShell
>   runtime resolves its value as true. If
>   the parameter is not specified, which
>   is typically the default, the
>   parameter value is resolved as false.

Comment: thanks I got it to work by using -UseParentTopNav:$true . But good to know the $true isnt necessary either.